# How to let several threads write to the same variable without mutex in Rust?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I am trying to implement an `outer` function that could calculate the outer product of two 1D arrays. Something like this:

```
use std::thread;
use ndarray::prelude::*;

pub fn multithread_outer(A: &Array1<f64>, B: &Array1<f64>) -> Array2<f64> {
    let mut result = Array2::<f64>::default((A.len(), B.len()));
    let thread_num = 5;
    let n = A.len() / thread_num;

    // a & b are ArcArray2<f64>
    let a = A.to_owned().into_shared();
    let b = B.to_owned().into_shared();

    for i in 0..thread_num{
        let a = a.clone();
        let b = b.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || {
            for j in i * n..(i + 1) * n {
                for k in 0..b.len() {
                    // This is the line I want to change
                    result[[j, k]] = a[j] * b[k];
                }
            }
        });
    }
    // Use join to make sure all threads finish here
    // Not so related to this question, so I didn't put it here
    result
}
```

You can see that by design, two threads will never write to the same element. However, rust compiler will not allow two mutable references to the same `result` variable. And using mutex will make this much slower. What is the right way to implement this function?

Comment: Where does `Array` come from? If it can give you a slice over its contents, then you can use [rayon](https://crates.io/crates/rayon) to get a parallel iterator.

Comment: Or you can use [`split_at_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut) to get two mutable sub-slices and move one to each thread if you want to do it by hand.

Comment: Also might be possible to use [`cell_view`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.cell_view) in order to get a view of Cells, though I don't know if that's thread-safe.

Comment: "What is the right way to implement this function?" have you considered [the built-in dot product](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/linalg/trait.Dot.html)?

Comment: Where does `i` come from in this code excerpt?

Comment: @prog-fh: I'd guess there's a missing loop to spawn `thread_num` threads, which would likely be indexed by `i`.

Comment: I **assume** this is `ndarray`? Please specify those things in your example. And as people already pointed out, `i` is never declares. Please [edit] your question to make your example a [MRE].

Comment: @prog-fh Sorry, I miss the loop that spawns threads. I have edited it.

Comment: @Finomnis: I have modified the question. You are right, this is actually ndarray.

Comment: Fyi: `let a = A.to_owned().into_shared();` is the wrong way to solve the problem that `A` and `B` are inaccessible from the threads. Use [`thread::scope`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/fn.scope.html) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is possible to do manually (with `thread::scope` and `split_at_mut`, for example), `ndarray` already has parallel iteration integrated into its library, based on `rayon`:

https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/parallel

Here is how your code would look like with parallel iterators:

```rust
use ndarray::parallel::prelude::*;
use ndarray::prelude::*;

pub fn multithread_outer(a: &Array1<f64>, b: &Array1<f64>) -> Array2<f64> {
    let mut result = Array2::<f64>::default((a.len(), b.len()));

    result
        .axis_iter_mut(Axis(0))
        .into_par_iter()
        .enumerate()
        .for_each(|(row_id, mut row)| {
            for (col_id, cell) in row.iter_mut().enumerate() {
                *cell = a[row_id] * b[col_id];
            }
        });

    result
}

fn main() {
    let a = Array1::from_vec(vec![1., 2., 3.]);
    let b = Array1::from_vec(vec![4., 5., 6., 7.]);

    let c = multithread_outer(&a, &b);
    println!("{}", c)
}
```

```
[[4, 5, 6, 7],
 [8, 10, 12, 14],
 [12, 15, 18, 21]]
```